# Why Log4j2 deletion policy is not working?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

Application creates logs based on the application name and entity name, but lo4j deletion policy is not working .

```
  -- For app1
    -Dapp.name=books
    -Dentity.name=The_Little_Prince

-- For app2
    -Dapp.name=sports
    -Dentity.name=Badminton
```

Refer the given below log4j config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="1" packages="">
    <Properties>
        <property name="baseDir">/apps/log/${sys:app.name}</property>
        <Property name="filename">${sys:entity.name}</Property>
        <Property name="loglevel">ERROR</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            
        </Console>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="App-File-Appender"
            fileName="${baseDir}/${filename}.log" filePattern="${baseDir}/${filename}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz">
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy >
            <Delete basePath="${baseDir}/" maxDepth="1" >
                <IfFileName glob="${filename}-*.log.gz" />
                <IfLastModified age="7d"/>
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <!-- Setting log level for each package is optional -->
        <!-- Optional begin -->
        <logger name="org.springframework" level="${loglevel}" />
        <logger name="org.apache" level="${loglevel}" />
        <logger name="org.eclipse" level="${loglevel}" />
        <logger name="sun.net" level="${loglevel}" />
        <!-- optional end -->
        <Root level="${loglevel}" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="App-File-Appender" />
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I am using

> Java 1.8, Spring boot version 2.7.6, Log4j 2.17.1

Comment: I have referred the given below link- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.7/manual/appenders.html

Comment: Changed from RollingRandomAccessFile  to RollingFile - still old archived files not been deleted.